# Using Linq to convert KeyValue pairs into Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject

Tags: c#, linq, json.net

I am trying to use C# LINQ to build a JObject.  I know that I can use a loop, such as,

```
var jobj = new JObject();
foreach (var field in fieldList)
{
    jobj[field.Name] = new JValue(field.Value);
}
```

Is it possible to replace the loop with LINQ?  I tried this,

```
var data = fieldList.Select(field => new KeyValuePair<string, JValue>(field.Name, new JValue(field.Value)));
var jobj = new JObject(data);
```

but it fails with this error:

```
Could not determine JSON object type for type System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2[
     System.String,Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue].
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here

```
jobj[field.Name] = new JValue(field.Value);
```

you actually are calling the following `JObject` indexer:

```
public JToken this[string propertyName] { get; set; }
```

i.e. you are setting the `JObject` property.

So the LINQ equivalent will be like this:

```
var data = fieldList.Select(field => new JProperty(field.Name, field.Value));
var jobj = new JObject(data);
```

Comment: Awesome!!! that is very helpful.  I was able to also add a `Where()` before the `Select()` to get only the fields I want.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't know if it's any prettier, but you could use Aggregate:

```
fieldList.Aggregate(new JObject(), (obj, next) => {obj[next.Name] = new JValue(next.Value);  return obj;})
```

It would be nice if JObject had a chainable API, but it doesn't seem to.

Comment: I should note, I didn't actually test this code... But the principle should is valid. It seems like you're trying to do a `reduce` (take a list and reduce it down to a single value: JObject).